# Create a radial gradient mask to create a hole in the picture

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, ios10, image-masking

I want to create a radial gradient mask to create a hole in the picture, so that you can see through the picture. I created an overlaying image with a hole and the image beneath is visible, like below:

[image]

I am able to create this image using `CGImageMaskCreate()` successfully. But due to the unusual behaviour of `CGImageMaskCreate()` in iOS 10.0, I am looking for another solutions.

One such solution is to create image mask using the UIView's `maskView` property. I am able to write the code for creating the above mentioned image effect using `maskView`. But its not giving the correct results.

I am not very good with Core Graphics, maybe that's why I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong. My code is:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
CGSize size = self.view.bounds.size;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGFloat radius = 160.0;
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(150.0, 150.0);
CGFloat components[] = {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,   1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,    1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,     1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,    1.0,1.0,1.0,0.5,    1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0};
CGFloat locations[] = {0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0};

//creating bitmap context
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, size.width, size.height, 8, size.width*4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
//creating gradient
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, components, locations, 6);
CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, gradient, center, 0.1, center, radius, 0);
//get the gradient image
CGImageRef imageHole = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageHole];
CGGradientRelease(gradient);

//creating mask view whose alpha channels will be used for masking
UIImageView *maskImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, 50.0, 100.0, 100.0)];
[maskImgView setImage:img];

//This is the view on which I want to perform masking
UIImageView *mainView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[mainView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"insta-logo.png"]];
mainView.maskView = maskImgView;
[self.view addSubview:mainView];
```

This the result I am getting:

[image]

The image used is entirely filled with red color. I want the resulting image to be transparent in the gradient region so that you can through it and I want the rest of the area to be red preserving the opacity of the rest of image, like the very first picture I posted.

I want to create this effect using `maskView` property, because of the unusual behaviour of `CAShapeLayer` and `CGImageMaskCreate()` encountered in iOS 10 and later.

Any suggestions will be very helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: "the unusual behaviour of CAShapeLayer and CGImageMaskCreate() encountered in iOS 10 and later" What exactly are you referring to?

Comment: Using CGImageMaskCreate() creates the mask properly but the final masked image is almost transparent. For my application, this problem occurs only in iPhone 7 and above. I suppose thats because of some issue with iOS 10.

Comment: By the way, I got some help from this thread https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50854

Comment: No, I really don't see the relevance of that; it's about some dumb stuff people have been trying to with UIVisualEffectView, which has nothing to do with your question. As for CGImageMaskCreate(), I think I can pretty much guarantee that it hasn't changed its behavior since iOS 3; Apple wouldn't mess with something at such a deep level so basic to the drawing system. Nor do I believe that hardware would make a difference. Apologies for the skepticism, but there it is. However, I never use CGImageMaskCreate() so I can't pretend to real knowledge.

Comment: The information which I got from this thread is to use maskView property. I really couldn't figure out why the same piece of code working fine on iPhone 6 is giving this problem. Just now one of friend told that its working fine on iPhone 6 running iOS 10. So now I just don't have any clue why its not working on only iPhone 7. Initially I thought maybe it could be because of the wide color gamut introduced in iPhone 7.

Comment: I am having this exact same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41151557/xcode-8-coregraphics-issue-with-iphone-7-running-ios-10

Comment: I always use either CALayer `mask` or UIView `mask` (as I did in my answer below) so, as I said, I don't really know about CGImageMaskCreate. Your guess about wide color is devilishly clever. You're certainly punching radial holes in my skepticism.

Comment: Well that's a wild guess since the problem is occurring in a specific device and not in a specific OS.

Comment: In iOS 10, the way to cope with wide color is to use the new UIGraphicsImageRenderer class, with a UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat whose `prefersExtendedRange` is appropriately set, to get your image format. Perhaps you need to steer clear of `CGBitmapContextCreate`, which has not been updated for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're describing is something like this:

[image]

As you can see, I've punched a radial-gradient hole in an image view, allowing the yellow background to show through.

How was that done? It's a CIFilter (`"CIRadialGradient"`) with clear and black color values, used as the `mask` of the image view.

Comment: The problem with _your_ code is that you have no clear center in your gradient; instead of fading from a clear center to a black outside, you fade from a black center to a clear outside. In effect, your color array `components` is backwards — that's all. Fix that, and your code will work fine. Mine is the way I would probably do it, but your way provides more precise control, so go right ahead and do it your way.